# Is there any ways to use IF ELSE statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the statement I use and same query works fine in SQL Server.

```
IF EXISTS (select CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3' month ) 
BEGIN
   SELECT 1 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 2
END
```

But I get below error in dbeaver.

SQL Error :

> mismatched input 'IIF'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CALL', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DENY', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT', 'MERGE', 'PREPARE', 'REFRESH', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TRUNCATE', 'UPDATE', 'USE',

I'm trying the build SP in Dbeaver to Select and create data into temp table and then compare the data from temp table and show the final result.

May be like

```
if EXISTS ( temp table available  ) 
BEGIN
   drop temp db.
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    Create a temp Db using sql queries 
    and start comparing the 2 results set 
    and bring out the required data. --> Planning to do something like this.

END
```

Comment: You might want to use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table; CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table;`

Comment: Every mysql statement has to be terminated , if syntax is IF..THEN..END IF; Please publish your full sp attempt.

Comment: MySQL does not support anonymous codeblocks rather than SQL Server.

Comment: @Akina is there any work around?

Comment: @P.Salmon What im trying to do is..
Drop if any temp table1 or 2 is available and then 

Create a temp table 1 and insert the select statements where i have applied certain conditions.
Then
Create another temp table 2 and insert the select statements where i have applied certain conditions.

Then do a join operation on Temp table 1 & 2 and bring the required result. 


So far i was doing the below things manually in Dbeaver and I thought of writing Stored Procedure but the above thing i was able to do in MS SQL Server but in dbeaver I'm facing issues.

Comment: Conditional statements are only allowed in mysql stored routines.